# Angular change scss object variables

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, sass

hey i have the following problem:

in my ionic / angular app i have a main (theme) scss where i have defined the main colors for the app some thing like this:

```
$colors: (
  primary:    #92c7ff,
  secondary:  #32db64,
  danger:     #6c1d23,
  light:      #f4f4f4,
  dark:       #222,
  btnColor:   #32db64,

);
```

and those i use in two ways

1) direct on the element

```
<button ion-button block type="submit" [disabled]="!loginForm.form.valid" color="btnColor">
```

or 2) as reference in another scss definition:

```
.background {       
        background: color($colors, light);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 100% 100%;
    }
```

in my usecase my user can define their app color design on my webserver. If they login, their custom design should be loaded. They should only be able to edit the colors and those should be overridden somehow in the app so all colors which where referenced from the main scss wont be used anymore but my own defined one. I found this article: https://nddt-webdevelopment.de/angularjs/angular-5-dynamic-css-component
Where it is possible to add custom css. and i started it this way but here i need to create a lot of css rules and dont have full control. For example the same button as before will be rendered in the app like this:

```
<button block="" color="btnColor" ion-button="" type="submit" class="disable-hover button button-md button-default button-default-md button-block button-block-md button-md-btnColor" ng-reflect-color="btnColor" ng-reflect-block="">
```

here i can find a ng-reflect-color tag. If i could intercept this reflection and give my own value would be nice.
Else i would need to create a new rule (like i did now):

```
.button-md-btnColor { background-color: orange; }
```

this works but it is not a really nice way - also i have the problem that i have to create those rules for every ionic-element i use like, cause there are many different classes:

```
.item-md-btnColor { background-color: orange; }
```

one idea would be that i add an custom color class which could work. but i think the interception is the best and cleanest way.